# Can't find Visual Studio Code on windows 8.1 not in start screen

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just installed Visual Studio Code, and noticed I can't find it by searching in the start screen.

The default installation location is in %APPDATA%, which by default isn't indexed by Windows.

What's the solution to this? 
I've read that adding %APPDATA% to the indexing can slow it down considerably because of the sheer number of files there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same thing on Windows 10, and this is what I learned:

I found that it's in: C:\Users\ **USERNAME** \Appdata\Local\Code\ **APPVERSION** \code.exe

where USERNAME is the username on the computer, and APPVERSION is the version of code installed (example, my folder is **app-0.5.0** so it would be in **C:\users\user1\appdata\local\code\app-0.5.0\code.exe**

I right-clicked on Code.exe and chose "Pin to Start" and now I can launch VS Code from start menu.

What's even stranger (to me), is Code installed into the user directory of the user account that I'm not logged into at the moment. I have user1 and user2. I'm logged in as User1. Code installed in User2's Appdata directory!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, so I right clicked on a html file and selected open with vs code. Once the application was open, I pinned it to the taskbar. And now I can access it anytime.